# Trying to create instance of class throws vtable error in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, class, linker-errors

I am trying to create an instance of a the following class:

```
#ifndef Sik_GameEntity_h
#define Sik_GameEntity_h

class GameEntity {
    public:

        ~GameEntity(){};
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();
        void clear();

    protected:

    private:  
};


#endif
```

Each of these methods (minus the deconstructor) are fleshed out in my .cpp file.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < nEntities; i++ )
{
    GameEntity ent;
    ent.setup();
    entities.push_back(ent);
}
```

I'm creating an instance and inserting  it into a vector of Game Entity objects. When I create an instance, I get the following error from XCode:]

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "GameEntity::GameEntity()", referenced from:
      appCore::setup() in appCore.o
  "GameEntity::~GameEntity()", referenced from:
      appCore::setup() in appCore.o
      std::vector<GameEntity, std::allocator<GameEntity> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<GameEntity*, std::vector<GameEntity, std::allocator<GameEntity> > >, GameEntity const&) in appCore.o
      void std::_Destroy<GameEntity>(GameEntity*) in appCore.o
  "vtable for GameEntity", referenced from:
      GameEntity::GameEntity(GameEntity const&) in appCore.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I've tried adding a constructor, but it didn't make a difference, I still received the same errors. Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong in my class?

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention, I cleaned my build.

Comment: post your appcore::setup() routine, and it's includes

Comment: You need to post the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following NOTE and error means that you are trying to inline the constructor or setup method in your cpp file rather than the header file. Remove all inline keywords in your cpp file

```
 NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```